# Is there a way to make a script addon that extends the "factory default" export operators?

Tags: scripting, export, add-on

I'd like to extend the `bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx()` operator (the operator that is called when ***File -> Export -> Fbx*** is pressed) with some custom setting (a checkbox/toggle) that would allow the user to choose whether or not to also export a custom .json file in the same location (containing custom related data about the mesh).

So far I've thought of a few (non ideal) ways of accomplishing this:

1. Create a button or w/e that calls `bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx()` and also exports the .txt file. Unless there is a way to check the result of `bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx()` (i.e. did the user actually export, or did he cancel?), then this is not ideal as it could export the .txt file even if the user decided to cancel exporting the .fbx.
2. Find the code that Blender uses for `bpy.ops.export_scene.fbx()` and duplicate and edit it to allow for this. I'm unsure where to find this code, or if users are allowed to copy/extend it. It would also not be ideal because then I would have two buttons that do pretty much the exact same thing, just with one added checkbox setting being the difference.

Is there somehow a way to create an addon that just extends upon the default window blender displays when exporting an fbx?

Comment: To be more specific with what I'm planning on using this for: my project is going to make quite extensive use of splines/curves in an external program (Unity), and from the curve in Blender I'll be needing both the generated surface (the mesh using beveling/depth), and the points that define the actual curve. So it seems to make the most sense that I'd make a custom addon that includes both of these when I export. FWIW, I don't specifically need the .fbx format for this I don't think; .obj or other file formats would probably be okay, I just used the .fbx exporter as an example here.

Comment: With regards to your thought #1, most operators should return `{"CANCELLED"}` or raise an error if they don't complete successfully. I haven't tried this operator, but perhaps it's the same. I've looked into extending the built-in UI somewhat and it seems like a lot of it is in C rather than Python, so I'm skeptical about it (though I've never looked at the save dialog).

Comment: @ChrisHayes Thanks for the insights Chris. I gave it a bit more thought today and figured out an alternative way of doing things that allows me to get by for now (which involves storing the data inside the mesh via Custom Properties and hooking into Unity's asset import pipeline to retrieve it on the other end). Hmm yeah, perhaps I'll try out that #1 if this doesn't work out then. I guess modifying the built-in UI can be quite a hassle (at least relative to just wanting to do something simple). That clears things up quite a bit, thanks again :)